# Movie about a woman cutting the private part of a man who is a womanizer

Tags: identify-this-movie

There's a man who has a story as womanizer and probably has done some rapes. He is a white man with a short black mustache. He's about 40.

There's a blond woman about 40 who seems to pay a visit to the womanizer.
She let him flirt with her. The man realized the woman is "open" and carry her to his room. He get undressed while kissing her.

She says **"bring me some water"**. He brings the water, she drinks it and says **"now you drink"**. He lift the glass of water and begin drinking. Then she takes a knife she had been hiding and cuts his penis off. Before she leaves the man bleeding she says to him "**this is for...[*FEMALE NAME*]**"

In other scene, the man is in the hospital and an old man heard about the news and, for a few seconds, he shows a grieving face. Suddenly, he begin to laugh really out loud.

The womanizer committed suicide after being presented his lost member in a box.

The blond woman heard about the suicide and said **"He couldn't live with it...  or without it"**

**When I saw it?:** twenty years ago.

**Where?:** In Venezuela.

**How?:** on TV

**What language?:** Spanish

**Real life or animated?:** Real life.

**Was it in color?:** Yes.

Comment: That's a nicely detailed identification question, but kindly keep the title not too obvious.

Comment: Almost sounds like Hard Candy, but that was an American film.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found it: It was a Venezuelan telenovela called [Las dos Dianas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_dos_Dianas) (1992)

[episode 121](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4qef02_telenovela-las-dos-dianas-capt-121-c-la-venganza-de-danta-carmona_fun) (See minute 11:30)

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]